# Why does Lubuntu automatically reset my CPU into performance mode after a short time?

Tags: performance, lubuntu, cpufreq

If I put the CPU mode into powersave or ondemand, it works for some time (5-10 minutes) but after that time Lubuntu automatically sets the CPU to performance mode.

(I see it doing `sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` )

Any ideas to prevent that?

Comment: Does Jupiter help?

Answer (score 0):

From the top right hand gear-like icon, go to System Settings, where you will find an icon called **Power**. There you can select "**Suspend when inactive for** 'n' minutes. You can change this setting and see what happens.

If it is a laptop that you are using, it is better to read manufacturers instructions to see if there is a battery-saving feature installed by default.

Comment: The OP is using Lubuntu not Unity.